# How to increment numbers with iMacros?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, imacros

Here's my current iMacro code I need help with:

```
VERSION BUILD=8810214 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=http://www.example.com/link.php?do=add&mylist=current&u=99999
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:link.php?do=add&otherlist=&userid=99999 ATTR=NAME:confirm
```

I am trying to do two things but need a bit of help:

1. I used the number 99999 as an example, but each time the iMacro loops, I need that number to change.  It should start with the number 5 and continue infinitely from that number up until the iMacro stops looping.
2. The last command starting with `TAG POS=1` cannot always be completed because there isn't an input button on all pages.  Is there any way for it to just skip those pages or ignore the failure so that the loop will continue running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
VERSION BUILD=8810214 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !LOOP 5
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0
URL GOTO=http://www.example.com/link.php?do=add&mylist=current&u=99999
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:link.php?do=add&otherlist=&userid=99999 ATTR=NAME:confirm
```

How about if you use these few commands in your example?